# setting Accept-Encoding header in Angular2's http service

Tags: angular, http-headers

I'm trying to make my Angular2 app request a resource with the encoding set to gzip. The code compiles and runs fine but it appears unaffected by the addition of the gzip header. I can't even confirm the the header has been added since there is no sign of it in Safari's web inspector

```
  var contentTypeHeaders = new Headers();
  contentTypeHeaders.append('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');

  var options = new RequestOptions({
    method: RequestMethod.Get,
    url: url,
    headers: contentTypeHeaders
  });
  var req = new Request(options);


    return this.http.request(req)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be an automatic header added by the browser if it supports auto-un-gzipping. I can see it in the web inspectors for Firefox, Chrome and IE, but not Safari. Either it's so well embedded that it doesn't appear in the inspector, or Safari doesn't support it, which is unlikely. So the answer to my question is: Don't add the header yourself.